# Magento: get desription and image of child category

Tags: magento

I'm using this code to display the child categories of a specific category in Magento:

```
$parentCategoryId = 3;
foreach Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId)->getChildrenCategories() as $childCategory) {
     echo $childCategory->getName() . '<br />';
     echo $childCategory->getUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

That works quiet fine. But now I like to display description and category image of these child categories. I've tried it with the descriptions and added this line:

```
echo $childCategory->getDescription() . '<br />';
```

But the output is empty. Does anybody has an idea what I can do to display the description and later the category image?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one, its working fine at my end

```
<?php  
$parentCategoryId = 10;
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId)->getChildren();
$catArray = explode(',', $categories);
foreach($catArray as $child){
     $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child );
     echo $_child->getName() . '<br />';
     echo $_child->getUrl() . '<br />';
     echo $_child->getDescription() . '<br />';
}
?>
```

we will not get category description attribute from this function getChildrenCategories(). A better explanation about this function can be found here on [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552342/magento-getting-the-descriptions-from-a-sub-category)

Comment: It's a bad idea to load a Model in a foreach loop, this will increase your load time. It can be fin for just a few images, but it will not work well with a lot categories.